# Conda CMake not finding GCC -- Windows

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, cmake, conda

I'm running a conda environment on Windows to get a bash-similar environment (I'm a native Linux Mint user and this is my first time running Windows). But when I run `cmake` in my conda environment I get the following error:

```
-- Building for: NMake Makefiles
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:33 (project):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:33 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C://CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C://CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
CMake Error: Cannot open file for write: C://CMakeCache.txt.tmp
CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied
CMake Error: Unable to open cache file for save. C://CMakeCache.txt
CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied
```

I've installed GCC on my conda environment, but I'm not sure how to force CMake to find it.

UPDATE:

I was able to point the compiler to where `gcc` is installed, but now I get this error:

```
-- Building for: NMake Makefiles
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/aeglick/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda2/Library/mingw-w64/bin/gcc.exe
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: nmake /nologo cmTC_da93e\fast &&
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/aeglick/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda2/Library/mingw-w64/bin/gcc.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Users/aeglick/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda2/Library/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Users/aeglick/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda2/Library/mingw-w64/bin/gcc.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/aeglick/Documents/GEANT4.10.07/geant4-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):nmake /nologo cmTC_da93e\fast && The system cannot find the file specified
    Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: nmake /nologo cmTC_da93e\fast &&




  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:33 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/aeglick/Documents/GEANT4.10.07/geant4-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/aeglick/Documents/GEANT4.10.07/geant4-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: Set the `CC` and `CXX` environment variables to your compiler. It's looking for MSVC (`cl`) right now, and not GCC.

Comment: I was able to point my compiler to where `gcc` is installed, but have now it says that `gcc` won't successfully install a simple example. I've never seen this error before.